# Angular ng-view controller error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using ng-view in the index file and whenever I run it, this error appears in the console.
I've tried re-ordering the script files but it doesn't seem to work, it keeps giving the error about the  Argument "ContactController".

angular-route.js:1012 Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ng/areq?p0=ContactController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined at Error (native)

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="confusionApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head 
         content must come *after* these tags -->

    <title>Ristorante Con Fusion</title>    
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
<!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
    <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/"><img src="images/logo.png" height=30 width=41></a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#/">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"
                         aria-hidden="true"></span> Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/aboutus">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"
                         aria-hidden="true"></span> About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/menu">
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"
                         aria-hidden="true"></span> 
                         Menu</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#/contactus">
                     <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>         

    <header class="jumbotron">

        <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row row-header">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                    <h1>Ristorante con Fusion</h1>
                    <p style="padding:40px;"></p>
                    <p>We take inspiration from the World's best cuisines, and create
                     a unique fusion experience. Our lipsmacking creations will 
                     tickle your culinary senses!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
                <p style="padding:20px;"></p>
                <img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

        <div ng-view></div>

    <footer class="row-footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">             
                <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <h5>Links</h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-5">
                    <h5>Our Address</h5>
                    <address>
                      121, Clear Water Bay Road<br>
                      Clear Water Bay, Kowloon<br>
                      HONG KONG<br>
                      <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>: +852 1234 5678<br>
                      <i class="fa fa-fax"></i>: +852 8765 4321<br>
                      <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>: 
                         <a href="mailto:confusion@food.net">
                         confusion@food.net</a>
                    </address>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="nav navbar-nav" style="padding: 40px 10px;">
                        <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-google-plus" href="http://google.com/+"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id="><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-linkedin" href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter" href="http://twitter.com/"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-youtube" href="http://youtube.com/"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-social-icon" href="mailto:"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <p style="padding:10px;"></p>
                    <p align=center>© Copyright 2015 Ristorante Con Fusion</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

<!-- build:js scripts/main.js -->
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>   
 <script src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
     <script src="scripts/services.js"></script>
       <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>  



<!-- endbuild -->

</body>

</html>
```

Controllers.js:

```
angular.module('confusionApp', [])
        .controller('MenuController', ['$scope', 'menuFactory', function($scope, menuFactory) {

            $scope.tab ;
            $scope.filtText = '';
            $scope.showDetails = false;
            $scope.dishes=menuFactory.getDishes();
            $scope.select = function(setTab) {
                $scope.tab = setTab;

                if (setTab === 2) {
                    $scope.filtText = "appetizer";
                }
                else if (setTab === 3) {
                    $scope.filtText = "mains";
                }
                else if (setTab === 4) {
                    $scope.filtText = "dessert";
                }
                else {
                    $scope.filtText = "";
                }
            };

            $scope.isSelected = function (checkTab) {
                return ($scope.tab === checkTab);
            };

            $scope.toggleDetails = function() {
                $scope.showDetails = !$scope.showDetails;
            };

        }])

        .controller('ContactController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

            $scope.feedback = {Name:"",stars:""};

            var channels = [{value:"tel", label:"Tel."}, {value:"Email",label:"Email"}];

            $scope.channels = channels;
            $scope.invalidChannelSelection = false;

        }]) .controller('DishCommentController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

            //Step 1: Create a JavaScript object to hold the comment from the form

            $scope.submitComment = function () {
            console.log($scope.feedback.stars);
                var x;
                //Step 2: This is how you record the date
                x= new Date().toISOString();

                // Step 3: Push your comment into the dish's comment array

                 $scope.dish.comments.push({ rating:$scope.feedback.stars,comment:$scope.feedback.comments,
                      author:$scope.feedback.Name,date:x});
                //Step 4: reset your form to pristine

                    $scope.feedback = {comments:"", Name:"", stars:"" };
                    $scope.feedback.mychannel="";
                  $scope.feedbackForm.$setPristine();

                //Step 5: reset your JavaScript object that holds your comment
            }
        }])

        .controller('FeedbackController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

            $scope.sendFeedback = function() {

                console.log($scope.feedback);





            };
        }])


        .controller('DishDetailController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'menuFactory', function($scope, $routeParams, menuFactory) {

            var dish= menuFactory.getDish(parseInt($routeParams.id,10));                       
             $scope.dish = dish;
            var dish={
                          name:'Uthapizza',
                          image: 'uthapizza.png',
                          category: 'mains', 
                          label:'Hot',
                          price:'4.99',
                          description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                           comments: [
                               {
                                   rating:5,
                                   comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                                   author:"John Lemon",
                                   date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                                   author:"Paul McVites",
                                   date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:3,
                                   comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                                   author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                                   date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                                   author:"Ringo Starry",
                                   date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:2,
                                   comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                                   author:"25 Cent",
                                   date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               }

                           ]
                    };

            $scope.dish = dish;

        }]);
```

Services.js

```
angular.module('confusionApp')
        .service('menuFactory', function() {
            var dishes=[
                         {
                          _id:0,
                          name:'Uthapizza',
                          image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                          category: 'mains',
                           label:'Hot',
                          price:'4.99',
                          description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                           comments: [
                               {
                                   rating:5,
                                   comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                                   author:"John Lemon",
                                   date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                                   author:"Paul McVites",
                                   date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:3,
                                   comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                                   author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                                   date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                                   author:"Ringo Starry",
                                   date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:2,
                                   comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                                   author:"25 Cent",
                                   date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               }                                                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          _id:1,
                          name:'Zucchipakoda',
                           image: 'images/zucchipakoda.png',
                          category: 'appetizer',
                           label:'',
                          price:'1.99',
                          description:'Deep fried Zucchini coated with mildly spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a sweet-tangy tamarind sauce',
                          comments: [
                               {
                                   rating:5,
                                   comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                                   author:"John Lemon",
                                   date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                                   author:"Paul McVites",
                                   date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:3,
                                   comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                                   author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                                   date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                                   author:"Ringo Starry",
                                   date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:2,
                                   comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                                   author:"25 Cent",
                                   date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               }                                                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          _id:2,
                          name:'Vadonut',
                           image: 'images/vadonut.png',
                          category: 'appetizer',
                           label:'New',
                          price:'1.99',
                          description:'A quintessential ConFusion experience, is it a vada or is it a donut?',
                           comments: [
                               {
                                   rating:5,
                                   comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                                   author:"John Lemon",
                                   date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                                   author:"Paul McVites",
                                   date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:3,
                                   comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                                   author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                                   date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                                   author:"Ringo Starry",
                                   date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:2,
                                   comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                                   author:"25 Cent",
                                   date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               }
                                                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          _id:3,
                          name:'ElaiCheese Cake',
                           image: 'images/elaicheesecake.png',
                          category: 'dessert',
                           label:'',
                          price:'2.99',
                          description:'A delectable, semi-sweet New York Style Cheese Cake, with Graham cracker crust and spiced with Indian cardamoms',
                           comments: [
                               {
                                   rating:5,
                                   comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                                   author:"John Lemon",
                                   date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                                   author:"Paul McVites",
                                   date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:3,
                                   comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                                   author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                                   date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                                   author:"Ringo Starry",
                                   date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:2,
                                   comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                                   author:"25 Cent",
                                   date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               }                                                          ]
                        }
                        ];


                          this.getDishes = function(){
                                        return dishes;
                                    };
                    this.getDish = function (index) {
                                        return dishes[index];
                };


        });
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('confusionApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            // route for the contactus page
            .when('/contactus', {
                templateUrl : 'contactus.html',
                controller  : 'ContactController'
            })
            // route for the menu page
            .when('/menu', {
                templateUrl : 'menu.html',
                controller  : 'MenuController'
            })
            // route for the dish details page
            .when('/menu/:id', {
                templateUrl : 'dishdetail.html',
                controller  : 'DishDetailController'
            })
            .otherwise('/contactus');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reorder your scripts as:

```
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
```

In your `controller.js` replace:

```
angular.module('confusionApp', [])
```

with:

```
angular.module('confusionApp')
```